# Como abreviar horas em texto?

Tags: ortografia, sintaxe

Após pesquisar em alguns sites fiquei em dúvida por isso resolvi perguntar : 
Como abreviar horas em texto?

Ouvi que não posso escrever zero à esquerda em texto, então estaria errado escrever `09h05` e o certo seria `9h5`, mas este [site](http://www.recantodasletras.com.br/gramatica/1642545) recomenda `9h05`.

Também me disseram que `20:30h` está errado, mas achei referências nesse [site](http://www.tudosobreconcursos.com/materiais/portugues/como-escrever-horarios).

Então quais as regras oficiais para incluir horas em texto em português?

Comment: Provavelmente não há resposta para isto, mas: `Ouvi que não posso escrever zero a esquerda em texto` Onde? E porque não?

Comment: Um colega comentou, lembrando de aulas de português que ele teve.

Comment: O mais comum é 9:05 ou 9h05, com preferência para a primeira. Outras formas eu não acho aconselháveis. Para tempo decorrido também pode ser 2 h e 15 min.

Answer (score 13):

Penso que não exista nenhuma "notação oficial Portuguesa", mas segundo a Wikipédia a [Europa adoptou o Standard ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Europe) para representação de tempo; pelo que Portugal, pertencendo à União Europeia, deve em teoria utilizar oficialmente a mesma norma.

Segundo o [Standard ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) a representação oficial para o tempo é `hh:mm:ss` ou seja dois dígitos para horas dois apara os minutos e dois para os segundos resultando em `17:25:33`ou `08:06:09`

A [Hora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hour) o [Minuto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute) e o [Segundo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second) são as unidades standard de medição do tempo aceites no Sistema Internacional de Unidades SI com abreviatura **h** ou **hr**, **min** e **s** ou **sec**

Assim sendo diria que também seria correcto utilizar `17h30min` ou `09h56min30s`

No entanto em linguagem corrente penso que se possa utilizar qualquer outro formato como `17h30`, `17h30m`, `17:30m` (apesar do *m* ser a abreviatura de metro) ou simplesmente `17:30`.

Já `17:30h` me parece incorrecto uma vez que aparenta indicar que o 30 se refere às horas e não aos minutos.

Nunca ouvi que não se pode escrever o zero à esquerda, e à primeira vista diria que piora consideravelmente a legibilidade, podendo causar confusão ou dúvida com 9 horas e 50 minutos.

Adicionalmente na era digital uma boa razão para escrever os zeros à esquerda é que em meios informáticos é frequentemente necessário ordenar conteúdos (listas, ficheiros, células numa tabelas, linhas de texto, etc.) e muitos algoritmos de ordenamento não interpretam valores numéricos. Estes são tratados como trechos de texto, ordenados alfabeticamente, o que resulta no incorrecto ordenamento de caracteres de algarismos. A utilização do zero à esquerda minimiza frequentemente este problema.

Comment: De onde você tirou que **hr** e **sec** são aceitas pelo SI? Apenas **h** e **s** são. http://physics.nist.gov/Pubs/SP330/sp330.pdf página 32

Comment: Obtive essa informação dos links da Wikipedia indicados na própria resposta

Comment: E o link diz justamente que **h** é a forma do SI: *Although it is not a standard defined by the International System of Units, the hour is a unit accepted for use with SI, represented by the symbol h.*

Comment: Sim, **h** é a norma SI, e na primeira linha diz que **h** ou **hr** e **s** ou **sec** são abreviaturas comuns

Answer (score 4):

9h5min seria errado; o correto é ou 9h05min ou 09h05min. Ou, é claro, 9:05h. Mas como não se usam abreviaturas como AM e PM, 9 horas da noite serão 21:00h. Não há nenhuma regra que proíba usar zero à esquerda ao que eu saiba, e se havia está se tornando obsoleta em função da necessidade de organizar listas em textos computadorizados.

Mas isso é válido para as horas como tempo, digamos, absoluto; para intervalos de tempo o uso é diferente ("o trem chega daqui a três horas e dez minutos", ou "daqui a 3h e 10min", mas não "daqui a 3:10h").

O site que você dá como referência contém alguns erros e imprecisões, por exemplo:

*Em casos especiais, minutos, segundos e décimos poderão ser expressos desta forma: 1'25"5.*

De forma alguma; essa notação deve ser reservada para minutos e segundos angulares, e não de tempo.

E dizer que não se usa "quatro horas da madrugada" é válido para textos formais; qualquer conto ou romance não apenas usa, como na verdade deve usar, a expressão referida (ou, é claro, "quatro horas da manhã" ou apenas "quatro horas"). Da mesma forma quanto à recomendação de sempre usar números.

Ou:

*Cuidado com a concordância com minuto: Ele chegou aos 15 para as 9 horas. Isto é: Ele chegou aos 15 minutos para as 9 horas.*

Esse é um formato muito estranho, e eu sinceramente não me lembro de jamais ter lido ou ouvido isso. Nesse caso será sempre preferível dizer que o cidadão "chegou às 8 e 45" ou que "chegou faltando quinze para as nove".

*A madrugada vai da* (sic) *zero às 6 horas; a manhã, das 6 ao meio-dia; a tarde, do meio-dia às 18 e a noite, das 18 às 24 horas.*

A madrugada vai da meia-noite às seis, porém a manhã vai da meia noite ao meio-dia. Assim, "1 hora da manhã" não está incorreto. Usam-se também também construções como "onze horas da madrugada", num contexto irônico. E "sete horas da madrugada" me parece bem plausível, mesmo sem ironia, especialmente em locais e meses onde o sol nasce depois das sete).

Comment: Será que poderia explicar porque é que "9h5min" seria errado?

Comment: O formato '15 para as 9' ainda se usa frequentemente, pelo menos em Portugal. Ouço mais ser usado por pessoas mais velhas do que por jovens, como os meus avós por exemplo.

Comment: @Jorge B. 9h5min seria errado por que não é claro, podendo ser confundido com 9h50min.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos - "Quinze para as nove" se usa muito frequentemente no Brasil. O que absolutamente não se usa é essa construção proposta pelo site, "**aos** quinze para as nove". Usa-se "chegou quinze para as nove" - sem preposição, ou "chegou faltando quinze para as nove". E, claro, para desespero dos puristas, "chegou às quinze para as nove" também, mas não vou ao ponto de recomendar como forma correta ou preferível...

Answer (score 2):

Simples:

- Em artigos de opinião e textos informativos, usa-se sempre horas completas (22:09hrs) acompanhadas de números extensivos (22:09hrs (vinte e duas horas com nove minutos)) acompanhados de **hrs**.
- Em narrativas o uso pode ser simplificado (10:09hrs) porém o termo **hrs** é mantido.
- Sempre o /A/ antecessor às horas vai ser acentuado ou craseado.

Lembre-se: A língua portuguesa não passa de muitas exceções com algumas regras.

Answer (score 1):

Sem o ":" fica 09h20min e com ":" fica 9:20h

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2123)

Comment: @Peixoto na verdade é uma resposta, pouco completa, mas é uma resposta. Até está com um ponto positivo.